# Navigate to with state updated

Tags: reactjs

I have a confirm button that implements a request and redirect to an other component. How can I wait data before navigating to the new component?

```
const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    request
} = useHttp();


const confirmHandler = () => {
      request({
        url: API_PATH.create_coupledCertificates,
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        body: body,
      });
    }
    navigate(component, {
      state: { isLoading, error },
    });
  };
```

The problem is that in this way the isLoading and error variables don't have the updated values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `async/await` syntaxis:

```js
const confirmHandler = async () => {
    await request({
        url: API_PATH.create_coupledCertificates,
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        body: body,
    });
    navigate(component, {
      state: { isLoading, error },
    });
  };
```

or `Promise`

```js
const confirmHandler = () => {
    return request({
        url: API_PATH.create_coupledCertificates,
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        body: body,
    })
    .then(() => {
      navigate(component, {
        state: { isLoading, error },
      });
    }
  };
```